# How do I correctly use a removeBook(Book) method which takes a Book as an argument

Tags: java, object, arraylist, reference, bluej

I am asked to create a method called `removeBook(Book)` which takes a `Book` as an argument. I have two classes `Library` and `Book`, I am using an `ArrayList<Book>` and an `Iterator<Book>` in my `Library` class.

The problem I am having is, Im not sure how to reference the book I want removing.

For example:

If the argument was `removeBook(String aTitle)` then I could use `x.getTitle();` to match the titles and remove that book.

but because the argument is a book, I am lost on what to do.

Here is my method:

```
public void removeBook(Book nameOfBook) {

    Iterator<Book> it = books.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Book t = it.next();
   
        (An Identifier) id = //Some reference to the book I want to remove??

        if(id.equals(nameOfBook))
        {
            it.remove();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Book not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the `equals` method to compare objects (like a book).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to implement an `equals()` method in your `Book` object which will allow you to customise what conditions must be true to ascertain that you have found the correct `Book` to remove from your list. See https://www.sitepoint.com/implement-javas-equals-method-correctly/

In your `equals()` method, you will probably want to check if title and author match, assuming you don't have any other more unique fields.